# Docker push in Kubernetes container registry failing

Tags: docker, containers, google-kubernetes-engine, docker-registry, docker-push

The docker build was clearly successful as the docker image exists, but docker push keeps failing:

[image]

Why? And how do I fix it?

I also tried replacing the project name with the project ID from the dashboard as shown in the screenshot of the terminal, but to no avail.

I have already done `gcloud auth configure-docker` before.

---

**EDIT:** After tagging the docker image appropriately, and then trying to push it, I still get the same error:

[image]

Showing two runs, the latter with project ID in the name. It gives error too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got it working now. The build command needs to be changed, the guide I was following seems to be outdated now.

So in the guide I was following, the `gcr.io` was given in build command itself like so:

```
docker build -t gcr.io/pycaret-kubernetes-demo/insurance-app:v1 .
```

But now, the solution is to build it normally, without the `gcr.io`, like so:

```
docker build -t insurance-app .
```

And then, like the previous answerer says, we need to tag it appropriately as documented in [Google's official guide](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/pushing-and-pulling):

```
docker tag insurance-app gcr.io/endless-ability-365318/insurance-pycaret-demo:v1
```

The `insurance-pycaret-demo:v1` part is any name you choose to give the new image.

After that, `docker push gcr.io/endless-ability-365318/insurance-pycaret-demo:v1` works.

Answer (score 0):

First change your image name to the gcr.io/<your_project_id>/insurance_app:v1.
For that use following command.

```
docker image tag <image_id> gcr.io/<your_project_id>/insurance_app:v1
```

Then use again following command

```
the docker push gcr.io/<your_project_id>/insurance_app:v1
```

Because before push to the docker google cloud docker registry you have to format the image name using registry name and project id.

Comment: I ran `docker image tag image_id gcr.io/endless-ability-365318/insurance_app:v1`. but got the error `Error response from daemon: No such image: image_id:latest`

Comment: ok, ran `docker image tag image_id gcr.io/pycaret-kubernetes-demo/insurance-app:v1`, got the same exact error: `Error response from daemon: No such image: image_id:latest`

Comment: I've added a screenshot in the question under 'EDIT', showing the error I now get after following your suggestions.

Comment: If it succesfully get tagged you can see that name in images.